# SQL: Persisting a root_id in a three-level tree?

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join, adjacency-list

I have a simple three-level tree, currently stored as an adjacency list:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id int,
  name text,
  parent_id int);
```

It's read-only, and I often need to know the root category of any given category.  So I want to add a root_id column and persist it to avoid messy WHERE clauses, CTEs, etc.

My first try was:

```
update categories set root_id = parent.id
from categories as child
join categories as parent
on child.parent_id = parent.id
and parent.parent_id is null;
```

But `UPDATE` can't deal with joins [producing multiple rows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-update.html#AEN70375).  (This query was just for the level-2 categories; I would do a similar one for the third level.)

I know the answer involves turning the join into a subquery, but I can't think in self-joins and subqueries at once.  We're on PostgreSQL 9.0, so I don't have writeable CTEs (though I'm curious how this one would look).

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the root in each record, you can easily find it with a recursive query.

A small demonstration for chasing granddad. (here the convention is that any root has a parent_id = NULL; another convention could be parent_id=id; YMMV)

```
set search_path='tmp';

DROP TABLE categories;
CREATE TABLE categories
  ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , parent_id INTEGER references categories(id)
  , zname text
  );

-- Generate some data
INSERT INTO categories (id) SELECT * FROM generate_series (1,33);
UPDATE categories SET parent_id = 1 + id/4 WHERE id > 1;
-- uncomment the next line (and comment the previous) if you want a forest.
-- UPDATE categories SET parent_id = 1 + id/4 WHERE id > 3;
UPDATE categories SET zname = 'Zzz'::text || id::text;


-- SELECT * FROM categories;

WITH RECURSIVE tr AS (
    SELECT ca0.id as root
    , ca0.parent_id AS parent_id
    , ca0.id AS id
    , ca0.zname AS zname
    FROM categories ca0
    WHERE ca0.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT tr.root as root
    , ca1.parent_id AS parent_id
    , ca1.id AS id
    , ca1.zname AS zname
    FROM categories ca1, tr
    WHERE ca1.parent_id = tr.id
    )
SELECT * FROM tr;
```

Result:

```
 root | parent_id | id | zname
------+-----------+----+-------
    1 |           |  1 | Zzz1
    1 |         1 |  2 | Zzz2
    1 |         1 |  3 | Zzz3
    1 |         2 |  4 | Zzz4
    1 |         2 |  5 | Zzz5
    1 |         2 |  6 | Zzz6
    1 |         2 |  7 | Zzz7
    1 |         3 |  8 | Zzz8
    1 |         3 |  9 | Zzz9
    1 |         3 | 10 | Zzz10
    1 |         3 | 11 | Zzz11
    1 |         4 | 12 | Zzz12
    1 |         4 | 13 | Zzz13
    1 |         4 | 14 | Zzz14
    1 |         4 | 15 | Zzz15
    1 |         5 | 16 | Zzz16
    1 |         5 | 17 | Zzz17
    1 |         5 | 18 | Zzz18
    1 |         5 | 19 | Zzz19
    1 |         6 | 20 | Zzz20
    1 |         6 | 21 | Zzz21
    1 |         6 | 22 | Zzz22
    1 |         6 | 23 | Zzz23
    1 |         7 | 24 | Zzz24
    1 |         7 | 25 | Zzz25
    1 |         7 | 26 | Zzz26
    1 |         7 | 27 | Zzz27
    1 |         8 | 28 | Zzz28
    1 |         8 | 29 | Zzz29
    1 |         8 | 30 | Zzz30
    1 |         8 | 31 | Zzz31
    1 |         9 | 32 | Zzz32
    1 |         9 | 33 | Zzz33
(33 rows)
```

Comment: I think this is ideal but he expressly said he didn't want to or couldn't use a CTE

Comment: Well, I don't want a CTE for the real query (Rails/ActiveRecord has no idea how to use them), but I don't mind using one for the update, and that works perfectly - will edit the answer.

Comment: If you only want the "rvalue" (CTE), you can use the recursive query at the rightmost side of an UPDATE (or DELETE, or EXISTS) query. You could build a view around it, producing a given id's grandparent. Only to prove that CTE's are not necessarily messy...

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did (use it at the rightmost side of an UPDATE).  There's an edit pending review, since I don't have rights yet.. thanks for teaching me CTEs.